# Getting the next minimum join value when we don't have the join value

Tags: sql, plsql, hive

We need join the lookup table with eff_date. if that date is not available, we need to get the next minimum date value and the corresponding rate.

For Example,

Quote table:

[image]

Rate_lookup Table:

[image]

In this example,

```
select q.quote_id, r.rate
from quote q
left join rate_lookup r 
    on q.eff_date = r.eff_date;
```

this will bring only the matching records as below,

[image]

But I need to get the rate value of next minimum eff_date as below,
[image]

you are welcome to share your inputs on this.

Comment: Are you using PL/SQL or Hive?  They are quite different.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

A standard method that should work in any database is:

```
select q.quote_id, r.rate
from quote q join
     rate_lookup r 
      on q.eff_date <= r.eff_date
where r.eff_date = (select max(r2.eff_date
                    from rate_lookup r2
                    where r2.eff_date <= q.eff_date
                   );
```